# Which language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

A dumb question, I know, but I don't know where to ask or search:

http://pastebin.com/R764PmNg

What language is this written in?

Comment: Seems to be a part of this file - http://code.google.com/p/ikemen/source/browse/trunk/ssz/sff.ssz?spec=svn338&r=338

Comment: I remember that when I used to use C and C++ you could put any extension to the source and to the bin files while working on Unix systems, so yes, it could be C or C++.

Comment: It uses SDL, and the project is here http://code.google.com/p/ikemen/

Comment: Dogbert its right, it belongs here: http://code.google.com/p/ikemen/wiki/Description. Maybe its a project of a new language based on C++ syntaxis.

Comment: The project is a fighting engine clone http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.U.G.E.N

Comment: Put the code inline in the future. Don't make us go off to a link to look at it. But also include the link to where you found it, so we can see it in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little Googlefu, it appears to be [S-SIZE](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://sourceforge.jp/projects/ssz/wiki/FrontPage) which looks to be a proprietary language for a [M.U.G.E.N.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.U.G.E.N) clone called Ikemen?

Comment: Most of the code seems to be there but there are some DLLs and EXEs too. Not 100% sure all the code is there though.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is, it's related to http://sourceforge.jp/projects/ssz/ or http://code.google.com/p/ikemen/

Answer (score 0):

Man that looks like C or C++ but the extension is very strange...